# Relationship between linear predictor and conditional expectation function

Tags: mathematical-statistics, conditional-expectation, predictor

Let $Y$ denote log-earnings and $X$ denote years of completed schooling for a cohort of workers. Assume a random sample of size $N$ is available from this population. Let $D_x = 1$ if $X = x$ and $0$ otherwise. Assume that $X \in \{0, 1, \cdots, 16\}$ with positive probability attached to each support point. Let $\mathbb{E}^*[Y \mid D_1, \cdots, D_{16}] = \alpha_0 + \sum_{k=1}^{16} \gamma_{0, l} D_l$.

(i) What is the relationship between this linear predictor $\mathbb{E}^*[Y \mid D_1, \cdots, D_{16}]$ and $\mathbb{E}[Y|X=x]$?

(ii) Next, assume that $Pr(X=6)=0$, then is the linear predictor $\mathbb{E}^*[Y \mid D_1, \cdots, D_{16}]$ still well-defined?

For (i), is it true that $\alpha_0 = \mathbb{E}[Y|X=0]$, $\gamma_{0,1} = \mathbb{E}[Y|X=1]$, etc? If so, how can I prove this? For part (ii), I think the linear predictor is no longer well-defined... but I am not sure exactly, can anyone confirm? (and give a reason as to why it may not be well-defined anymore?)

Comment: Hint: you can show that linear-in-years regression yields the same intercept and slope coefficients as a weighted linear regression of average log earning within each education group on education group, with the weights being the number of observations in that education group. The average is what the dummy specification estimates. So the linear spec is is approximating the dummy regression, which is bad if there are non-linearities, but it can interpolate/extrapolate to levels of education not seen in the data, whereas the dummy version cannot. That is sometimes useful.

Comment: Right, I see, that makes sense. So, what if one category, in this case $X=6$, has zero probability of occurrence, then including $D_{6}$ in the regression would be not well-defined right? What would be the reason though?

Comment: Your software will drop $D_6$ from regression because otherwise the matrix will not be invertible since the intercept and $D_6$ are perfectly collinear.